# How to get text from element using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to write an assert to compare the expected text with the actual one. To do this, I need to pull out the text. Here is the code:

```
<div class="checkout-list">
  <div class="notification notification__inform " id="inform-not-product">
   <div class="message">
    <div class="text">
     "some test text"
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]')))
information_message = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]').text()
```

I get an error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/automation/tests/sales/1.py", line 130, in 
information_message = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]').text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*

Also i tried to do the same with XPATH

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]/text()[1]')))
information_message = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]/text()[1]').text()
```

and i get another error:

*selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[contains(@id, "inform-not-product")]//div[contains(@class, "text")]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.*

Pls help(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` is not exist in selenium. you need to use only `text`

Use `visibility_of_element_located()` instead of `presence_of_element_located()`

You can ignore contains since it doesn't contains dynamic string.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="inform-not-product"]//div[@class="text"]')))
    information_message = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="inform-not-product"]//div[@class="text"]').text
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question: how to distinguish dynamic from non-dynamic?